# How to compress 2GB to 300 mb using python library

Tags: python, compression

I've one million of string data and writing into a file, I'm using Python gZip compression which comes around 2gb of size, I want to reduce into 250-300 MB?

Is there any way to compress more and bring it to 300 MB?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying your compressed, gzip data is 2 GB (implying your uncompressed data is somewhat larger)? I'm not aware of a general purpose compression algorithm that is an order of magnitude better than gzip, but your specific data may have properties that can be exploited to compress further.

Comment: There are limits of lossless compression. If you used gzip properly it is very unlikely you will be able to compress it that far further. Even with the fastest profile the compression ratio to  the best compression is not 1:8.

Comment: What leads you to believe that it's even theoretically possible to reduce the information by another factor of 8?  Are you willing to accept data loss?  As a test, you could compute the Shannon entropy of your data; this can give you one measure of the compression possible.

Comment: I've update my sample program

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you can help gzip and other algorithms preprocessing the data before compression.

For instance, if you have an image, instead of compressing the raw pixel data, you can try to compress the differences between the current pixel and the previous one.

So, instead of just compressing your string data, try pre-processing it before using your knowledge about the data itself.

Do not just compute deltas between characters: try normalizing stuff to reduce variance (remove unneeded characters, whitespace between the last character and end of line, unneeded whitespace, etc).

If your string data is composed by fields (usually it is), another technique that works is compressing the columns instead of the rows. Columnar data tends to have less variance and gzip will exploit that easily.

Keep in mind going from 2GB *compressed* data to *300M* compressed will be quite hard to achieve, and you might need to process the data after decompressing in order to be usable.

Comment: I've removed all extra spaces, and value is not required from my test data. I've update my sample code